# Tibco Soap Reply send xml in CDATA in param without converts < to "&lt;"?

Tags: xml, soap, cdata, tibco

How can I prevent Tibco autoconvert in the Soap Reply activity when I send xml data(in CDATA) in request?

For example,

I want to send:

```
<string1><![CDATA[<root><elem>1</elem></root>]]></string1>
```

But Tibco sends:

```
<string1>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;root&gt;&lt;elem>1&lt;/elem>&lt;/root>]]></string1>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Tibco expects you to give it a string and let it handle the serialization of that string as XML.  If you tell it to send the string

```
<root><elem>1</elem></root>
```

then it should escape it properly as something like

```
<string1>&lt;root>&lt;elem>1&lt;/elem>&lt;/root></string1>
```

which is exactly equivalent to

```
<string1><![CDATA[<root><elem>1</elem></root>]]></string1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just mapp your **root** element directly with the input schema of Soap Reply activity, Tibco will add CDATA for you without autoconvert the **"<"** character.

I tried that with Tibco BW 6.X, and it works.